# Why console.log(isFinite('0/2')); //false and console.log(isFinite(0/2)); //true

Tags: javascript, numbers

I saw that `isFinite` will check if not number, it will convert to number. After that it checks the converted number is finite or not. But why it return different output when I passed '0/2' as a string and 0/2 as a number.

I tried to check but don't understand why they don't have the same output.

```js
console.log(isFinite('1e9')); //true
console.log(isFinite(1e9)); //true

console.log(isFinite('0/2')); //false
console.log(isFinite(0/2)); //true
```

Comment: `'0/2'` isn't a number, its a expression.

Comment: It’s gonna convert to a number, it’s not gonna evaluate mathematical expressions from a string.

Comment: `console.log(isFinite(eval('0/2')));` would also be true, but don't use eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isFinite` can convert a string value. If the value can be converted to Number, it will show `true` for finite and `false` for infinite values.

However, if value in a string cannot be converted to Number, return value will always be `false`

In your case, `'0/2'` is an expression in string and cannot be converted to Number without mathematical operation.

`isFinite` only converts and does not do operation. So return value is `false`